# How to reference properties and methods from form within TypeScript controller?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have a simple question that I haven't found an answer to yet.

In regular Angular JavaScript, if I have the beginning of a form like this:

```
<form novalidate action="" class="signupForm" name="signup.form">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 ">
            <fieldset>
                <input type="text" name="fullName" placeholder="Full Name" ng-model="signup.fullName" required />{{signup.fullName}}
                <div ng-show="signup.form.$submitted || signup.form.$touched">
                    <span ng-show="signup.form.$error.required">Please enter your full name.</span>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Using `controllerAs` for example, using `SignupCtrl as signup` with UI Router, I can reference my form in my controller like this:

```
.controller(function() {
     this.form // shows me my form
 });
```

However, in TypeScript, `this` refers to my class and its own variables and methods, unless I am mistaken. How can I reference the form, or anything, in my TypeScript controller? How is scope bound to the view now?

```
export class SignupCtrl implements ISignupCredentials {                     

        constructor(protected $http: ng.IHttpService, 
                    protected $q: ng.IQService,
                    protected $scope: IScope) {                                                

            console.log(this.form); // undefined because form doesn't exist in my controller class                                    
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

We do it like this:

```
function myDirective(): ng.IDirective
{
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: 'template.html',
        controller: 'MyController',
        scope:
        {
        },
        link: (scope, element, attrs, controller: MyController) =>
        {
            scope.vm = controller;
        }
    };
}

angular.module('mod').directive("mydirective", myDirective);

export class MyController
{
    public ImOnHTML: string = "helloWorld";

    static $inject = [];
    constructor()
    {

    }
}

angular.module('mod').controller('MyController', MyController);
```

and then in the template.html all of your controllers properties will be on `vm.`

so:
     `<input ng-model="vm.ImOnHTML"/>`

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This does imply though, that you must create a directive in order to tie the model to the view with scope. Is there another way to do this using just the controller? Ie. reference the form directly from the controller without creating a directive?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think what you're doing is pretty close.

As you know, when you give your `<form>` the name "signup.form" and you are using "controller as" syntax, Angular will add a reference to your form to your controller so that it can be referenced as "signup.form". [[1]](http://www.technofattie.com/2014/07/01/using-angular-forms-with-controller-as-syntax.html)

Using TypeScript doesn't change this. But to keep the compiler happy, you have to add the appropriate property to your class. In this case "form":

```
export class SignupCtrl implements ISignupCredentials {                     
    form: any;

    constructor(protected $http: ng.IHttpService, 
                protected $q: ng.IQService,
                protected $scope: IScope) {

    }
}
```

Also, `this.form` will be `undefined` until Angular sets its value, which won't have happened yet when your `constructor()` method is executed.